# Link phone provider with email provider in Firebase (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, password-less

How can one link the phone provider with the email provider in authenticated users section from Firebase?

Whenever I try to log in with the email, it then removes the phone number from the identifier section and then I try to log in with the phone number it creates a new user with a different UID.

I am looking for a solution in Swift that would have both phone and email as providers, any advice?

[image: Firebase Authentication]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link multiple Auth providers as explained in [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking)

```
// If email & password
// let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)
// If email link
let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, link: link)
Auth.auth().currentUser.link(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I am using the email passwordless link as an authentication method.

Comment: Updated answer :)